# Laravel and Dropzonejs files not uploading

Tags: php, laravel-4, dropzone.js

I have been working with Laravel and Dropzone JS so I can have a drag and drop file upload feature but it isn't seeming to want to upload.

This is my blade.php file, starting the form and it displays how I want it, but I think my issues are in the action tag.

```
<form class="dropzone" id="images-dropzone" method="post" action="{{ url('/upload') }}"></form>
```

Then in my routes file I have a very simple setup to catch it, but it does not seem to ever get here.

```
Route::post('/upload', function(){
    $file = Input::file('file');
    $directory = 'uploads/test/';
    $upload_success = Input::file('file')->move($directory, $file);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the form I think.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" id="images-dropzone" method="post" action="{{ url('/upload') }}"></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to setting the enctype, check that `upload_max_filesize` in the PHP config allows the size of the file you are uploading. If you upload a larger file, it won't even show up if you log `$request->all()`

Suggestion from this thread: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/485#issuecomment-44801310